# Enable letsencrypt for Gitlab CE Pages

Tags: git, gitlab, letsencrypt

I run a self-hosted Gitlab CE server (12.1.3-ce.0) and try to enable SSL support for Pages, but with no success. I enable letsencrypt for Pages on:
"Admin area --> Settings --> Preferences --> Pages ", check “accept term” and enter valid email.
However on “Projects --> Edit --> Setting --> Pages” I see “Support for domains and certificates is disabled. Ask your system’s administrator to enable it.”

I enable letsencrypt on gitlab.rb file (letsencrypt[‘enable’] = true) but that didn’t change anything.

Should I add some more options?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you follow all the steps and verified the configured values given in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl.html)?

Comment: Yes, and for the main instance, letsencrypt work fine.

Comment: For GitLab 12.1, does [this procedure](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/custom_domains_ssl_tls_certification/lets_encrypt_integration.html) for automatic integration apply to your case?

Comment: Yes, this can be seen from my question.